# How can I tell which sessions are tracing (after a call to DBMS_MONITOR.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE)

Tags: oracle

Is there a data-dictionary view or some other way of telling which (if any) sessions currently have tracing enabled (after a call to DBMS_MONITOR.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE)?

(At the minute I keep running an `ls` on the udump folder, but this isn't exactly foolproof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic V$SESSION view has this info:

select * from v$session where sql_trace = 'ENABLED'